# How to display the number of mistypes in js after the game is over?

Tags: javascript

The subject will be displayed randomly, and if you write any of (same value, different value, empty value) in the text box, click and press the OK button, you will proceed to the next problem even if the values are not exactly the same. After repeating this process 5 times, I would like to display the number of erroneous inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this if/else if block:

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {

  if(e.key === questionList[question].charAt(index) ){
    document.forms[0].elements[0].value = "";
    index++;

  } else if (e.key === 'Shift') {
    ;

  } else if(index == questionList[question].length){
    document.forms[0].elements[0].value = "";
    index++;

  } else if(e.key !== questionList[question].charAt(index)){
    typecount++;
  } else {
    typemiss++;
  }
});
```

The if statement at the beginning checks this:
`e.key === questionList[question].charAt(index)`

The else if statement before the else checks this:
`e.key !== questionList[question].charAt(index)`

One or the other will be true. Which means it will never reach the else where you have the `typemiss` counter incremented.

I have not checked if the following works completely like you wanted but it could help find the error for you:

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  var isTyping = false;

  if(e.key === questionList[question].charAt(index) ){
    document.forms[0].elements[0].value = "";
    index++;
    isTyping = true;

  } else if (e.key === 'Shift' || e.key === 'Alt') {
    ;

  } else if(index == questionList[question].length){
    document.forms[0].elements[0].value = "";
    index++;

  } else if(e.key !== questionList[question].charAt(index)){
    typemiss++;
    isTyping = true;
  }

  if (isTyping) {
    typecount++;
  }
});
```

Comment: I fixed the code, but it didn't do what I wanted to do.

Comment: Well a way would be debugging. Add `console.log()` calls and output where you are and the variable, for example `console.log('typemiss', typemiss);`. This helps you see what does what in which order. You can provide a working example with jsfiddle or CodePen if you want.

Comment: That's right,But I want to do the following.The subject is displayed randomly, and if you enter one of each (same value, different value, empty value as the question) in the text box and press the ok button, you will go to the next question and repeat it 5 times. When the ok button is pressed the five times, the number of characters that the theme and the value entered by the user are incorrect is displayed.

Comment: Okay sure so you should debug that then. All that is missing is that you make sure all the if / else if branches work correctly and the sums work as you expect them to. I was just trying to help but I'm sorry but I don't have time to write your code for you.

Comment: I tried console.log ('typemiss', typemiss); but it was just counting the number of types.Thank you for just commenting.

Comment: Sure you're welcome. Shouldn't `typecount++;` and `typemiss++;` be swapped then in your code? Testing for `!==` should update the typemiss count, right?

Comment: Where should I enter typemiss ++;　If you apply typemiss ++; to the(! == )conditional expression,

Comment: This will cause typemiss ++; and typecount ++; to appear  with the same number of types. Also, it is not possible to determine the number of typos when blank.